# Mouseenter&Mouseleave to Click

Tags: javascript, click, mouseenter

I have iframe pages which shows up when you hover. I want to change this to click. Somehow it's not working.

JS:

```
$('section div').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css('height', '80vh');
    $(this).css('width', '100%');
    $('#info').css('width', '100%');
});

$('section div').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css('height', '2.5vh');
    $(this).css('width', '100%');
    $('#info').css('width', '100%');
});
```

CSS:

```
iframe {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 1s;
    z-index: 2000;
}

#info {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 80vh;
    width: 100%;
    transition: 1s;
    z-index: 1;
}

section {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <section></section>
</body>
```

Sometime my tryout worked out, but only on the iframe itself(blank), therefore nothing happens when the iframe is filled with content, maybe it's only a problem of target.

Comment: Where’s your `click` code?

Comment: The click code I made is not working at all. Here is what I want to achieve on click, instead of mouseenter and mouseleave: jsfiddle.net/T73A/tsq8h6pc

Comment: The non-working code needs to be in the question itself.

Comment: Here it is: $('section div').click(function(){ $(this).css('height', '80vh'); $(this).css('width', '100%');$('#info').css('width', '100%');});

Somehow, I can't get the right hitbox, I'm trying something else now.

Comment: _In the question itself_. Not as a comment with missing formatting.

Comment: I'm sorry, next time I will write it more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your question and your `click` code is missing. From what I hardly understand, you could achive this with this code:

```js
$('section div').click(function() {
  // This part is not really needed
  if (this.state === undefined) {
    this.state = 0;
  }
  // end of not needed part
  if (this.state) {
    $(this).css('height', '2.5vh');
    $(this).css('width', '100%');
    $('#info').css('width', '100%');
    this.state = 0;
  } else {
    $(this).css('height', '80vh');
    $(this).css('width', '100%');
    $('#info').css('width', '100%');
    this.state = 1;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  section {
    margin: 10px;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <section>
    <div style="background-color: red; height: 2.5vh; width: 100%"></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div style="background-color: green; height: 2.5vh; width: 100%"></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div style="background-color: blue; height: 2.5vh; width: 100%"></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div style="background-color: black; height: 2.5vh; width: 100%"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is what I want to achieve on click, instead of mouseenter and mouseleave: https://jsfiddle.net/T73A/tsq8h6pc/

Comment: I see whats happening, the div has wierd hitbox, give me 10 mins

Comment: Ok, so the bug is the same, the div has a wierd hitbox. The only workaround that i can see is to make a handler div that would trigger the click event.

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well, the click event can't get the right target. I will try to rethink it. thanks